Forcing HDMI Output During Windows Setup (PiKVM)
Forcing HDMI Output During Windows Setup (PiKVM)
Hello! I have a problem using my PiKVM to reinstall Windows on laptops. Specifically, my laptop (a Surface Book 2) doesn't output HDMI during the Windows setup process. Only the keyboard and mouse are functioning, but I can't get an HDMI signal for my PiKVM or an external monitor. Here's what I've tried so far:
Steps Already Tried:
Using Win + P to switch display outputs: This did not work during Windows setup.
Lid-close method: Closing the laptop lid during setup didn't force HDMI out either.
BIOS settings: There were no options to prioritize external displays or HDMI in the BIOS.
The Problem:
How can I get the Windows setup screen to display on an external monitor (or through HDMI output) rather than the built-in laptop screen? Is there a way to modify the Windows ISO or flash drive to force HDMI output so my PiKVM or external monitor receives the signal?

Absolutely nothing to do with raspberry pi, is 100% to do with Surface Book - perhaps find the appropriate stackExchange for that
